# Laravel: The use statement with non-compound name 'Cache' has no effect

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I have `centos7` `php56` `laravel 5` and `memcached` but when try `use Cache` in `routes.php` I get:

```
ErrorException in routes.php line 3:
The use statement with non-compound name 'Cache' has no effect
```

router.php

```
<?php

use Cache;
...
```

Comment: Have you tried googling your error? There are older stackoverflow questions that address this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745050/laravel-composer-the-use-statement-with-non-compound-name/23747053#23747053

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just remove **use Cache;** from your routes.php. It is not needed there as file itself is not associated with specific namespace. Once you remove it you will not see that warning again.

Answer (score 7):

That is because you are already in the global namespace. So when you do something like `use Cache;`, you are saying "when I say Cache, I mean \Cache". Because you already *are* in the global namespace, that statement has no effect. That's what the warning is about.